# isNan() and typeof not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a numeric input only field on the react-bootstrap  component. I know there is a type="number" attribute we could use but the type is set to password to mask the input.

I tried this at first but it didn't work:

```
handleAcessCodeChange(event) {
    isNan(event.target.value) ? this.setState({ [event.target.id] : event.target.value }) : console.log('Non-numeric input');
}
```

I then tried the long way which still didn't work:

```
if(isNaN(event.target.value)) {
  this.setState({ [event.target.id] : event.target.value });
}
else {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Error');
}
```

```
{/* Access code */}
<Form.Group controlId='accessCode'>
    <Form.Label>Access Code</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      style={{ width: '50%' }}
      type='password'
      placeholder='Enter access code'
      defaultValue=''
      autocomplete='off'
      value={this.state.accessCode}
      onChange={this.handleAcessCodeChange.bind(this)}
    />
</Form.Group>
```

I expected the page to display the error if a non numeric input was entered but it accepted everything. Is there a problem with my code or is it the implemented of the bootstrap  component?

Comment: You likely want to use `!isNaN(whateverVariable)` here. Not not a number is a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this was asked a while back but this question showed up when I was looking for the answer.

You may want to use Number.isNaN which is different than the global isNaN (need IE polyfill)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description

checkout some of these examples from the MDN:

```js
isNaN(NaN);       // true
isNaN(undefined); // true
isNaN({});        // true

isNaN(true);      // false
isNaN(null);      // false
isNaN(37);        // false

// strings
isNaN('37');      // false: "37" is converted to the number 37 which is not NaN
isNaN('37.37');   // false: "37.37" is converted to the number 37.37 which is not NaN
isNaN("37,5");    // true
isNaN('123ABC');  // true:  parseInt("123ABC") is 123 but Number("123ABC") is NaN
isNaN('');        // false: the empty string is converted to 0 which is not NaN
isNaN(' ');       // false: a string with spaces is converted to 0 which is not NaN

// dates
isNaN(new Date());                // false
isNaN(new Date().toString());     // true

// This is a false positive and the reason why isNaN is not entirely reliable
isNaN('blabla');   // true: "blabla" is converted to a number. 
                   // Parsing this as a number fails and returns NaN
```